# Install Python 3.7.3 from source with SSL failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, python, ssl

I am having troubles installing Python 3.7.3 with SSL.

All my compilations are successful, but the final install of module `_ssl` is failed.

Step 1: Install OpenSSL:

```
git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
cd openssl
git checkout tags/OpenSSL_1_0_2r
./Config
make
sudo make install
```

The OpenSSL is installed in `/usr/local/ssl`.

Step 2: Configure Python3.7.3

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tgz
tar xzvf Python-3.7.3.tgz
cd Python-3.7.3
./configure --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl
```

The configuration is correct:

```
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr/local/ssl... yes
checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works... yes
checking for X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host in libssl... yes
```

Step 3: compile python

```
make
```

Step 4a: install python

```
sudo make install
```

This step failed:

```
*** WARNING: renaming "_ssl" since importing it failed: build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/_ssl.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_hostflags
...
Following modules built successfully but were removed because they could not be imported:
_ssl
```

Step 4b: Install Python into a local folder:

```
make install prefix="~/Downloads/install"
```

The installation is successful in this case.

After step 4a `python3 -c "import ssl"` failed.

But if I replace the `_ssl` module compiled in step 4b, the above command works.

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu_failed.so
sudo cp ~/Downloads/install/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/
```

Could anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: --with-openssl did not worked for me, instead i solved by setting LDFLAGS https://bugs.python.org/issue34028#msg339455

Answer (score 0):

1. Compile OpenSSL and make install (if by default it will be installed under `/usr/local/ssl`); make sure to compile with shared option
2. Add its full path to the linker search config file: `/etc/ld.so.conf`
3. Type as root: `ldconfig`

Recompile.